# Error when using CKEDITOR.dom.node.remove() + downcast when using CKEDITOR's Widget API

Tags: ckeditor

I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of null` on line 2509 of plugin.js of the Widget Plugin.

We had no errors before but then converted our plugin to be a Widget and are having issues downcasting which prevent our CMS (Drupal + WYSIWYG plugin) from saving updated content.

We created a contextMenu item "delete" which uses CKEDITOR.dom.node.remove() and when we do that it throws the error on a downcast. Using the Clipboard plugin's keyboard 'cut' command does not throw errors on downcasting.

What is the proper way to destroy, remove, or delete a Widget from the editor?

I have tried http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-destroy but it isn't available. Also, it is not a block-level element that I tried to force inline (http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/inline-widget-error-on-downcast).

It is failing here, with element.getFirst() and then the error happens on `if ( widgetElement.attributes...` :

```
if ( 'data-cke-widget-id' in attrs ) {
                    widget = widgetsRepo.instances[ attrs[ 'data-cke-widget-id' ] ];
                    if ( widget ) {
                        widgetElement = element.getFirst( isParserWidgetElement );
                        toBeDowncasted.push( {
                            wrapper: element,
                            element: widgetElement,
                            widget: widget,
                            editables: {}
                        } );

                        // If widget did not have data-cke-widget attribute before upcasting remove it.
                        if ( widgetElement.attributes[ 'data-cke-widget-keep-attr' ] != '1' )
                            delete widgetElement.attributes[ 'data-widget' ];
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was developer error on my part. I wasn't remove()'ing the parent wrapper of the widget. If you get this error on a remove() make sure you inspect the DOM and make sure the widget wrapper is getting deleted. If it is still there you are doing it wrong and need to better target your remove().